# SQL - Only update field based on current condition, keep as is if otherwise in CASE Statement (SQL/SNOWFLAKE)

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a calculation I would like to only update on today's date. If it's not today's date, then I'd like yesterday's value to stay as is. (eg. If yesterday's value was .02, and today's value of this calculation is .03, I only want the field to be updated to .03 for today's value and yesterday's to stay at .02)

below is the full query that I'm trying to write.

i is a subquery that gives me the count of each day of the week in a month (eg. 5 mondays, 4 tuesdays etc).

h is a subquery that gives a daily ratio to report eg (20% of a certain count occurred on Mondays, 5% on tuesdays).

r is a calendar table.

```
SELECT
  i.month_name,
  i.day_name,
  i.cal_year,
  r.cal_date,
  case
    WHEN
        r.is_current_date = 1 then div0null(q,day_mult)
        else a
  end as a

FROM
  i
  LEFT JOIN h ON i.day_name = h.dn
  LEFT JOIN calendar AS r ON i.month_name = r.month_name
  AND i.day_name = r.day_name
  where r.is_current_month = 1
```

When I run this, I get an error that 'a' is an invalid identifier. How can I can I accomplish what I'm trying to accomplish?

Comment: What is the actual query (UPDATE/SELECT/DDL)? Please provide full text with table definitions.

Comment: @LukaszSzozda - I've updated the question with more detail.

Comment: a is an column alias and is a valid identifier. I could not reproduce your case - https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZRWG.png. I suggest to prefix columns `q`, `day_mult`, `maturity_dist` with table they belong to `i/h/r`.

Comment: Sorry about that @LukaszSzozda. I've updated the question. a is the field I'm trying to create. Maturity_dist is not an existing field in any of the previous ctes or tables.

Comment: `CASE WHEN ... THEN ... ELSE a END AS a` => if a is just introduced it cannot be part of case expression (it does not exist yet)

Comment: Understood thanks. How would you recommend accomplishing what I'm trying to do? I've thought of introducing the field in another CTE but I think it would update daily (when the query is scheduled to run). My aim is to freeze the values on all previous days that aren't today so I have a historical record of what the value(s) were in the past.